# R formatting problems

Tags: r

A portion of my data set

```
   lat_orig long_orig unit  value  Ag As Au Cu Fe Mn Pb
1:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm   -0.02  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
2:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm   15.00  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
3:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm 1000.00  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
4:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm   -0.50  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm   30.00  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

OK i would like to have the vars (Ag, As, Au, Cu, Fe, Mn, Pb) when equal to 1 be replace by the corresponding value in the value column. Then collapse all the rows so i only have one row for each lat_orig and long_orig (notice all the lat and long are the same). This is just a small portion of my overall data.

I am not sure were to start, any help would be appreciated.

desired output

```
   lat_orig long_orig unit    Ag    As    Au       Cu     Fe      Mn  Pb
1:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm    -0.50  0     -0.02    15.00  1000.00 0   30.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `melt/dcast`.  Assuming the dataset as `data.table`, convert it to 'long' format with `melt`, `filter` with a condition to get all the variable, then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(DT, id.var = 1:4, value.name = "val"
    )[, if(any(val==1)) .SD[val==1] else .SD[1L] , variable
   ][, value:= value*val], lat_orig+long_orig+unit~variable, value = "value")
#   lat_orig long_orig unit   Ag As    Au Cu   Fe Mn Pb
#1:  40.5525 -106.7736  ppm -0.5  0 -0.02 15 1000  0 30
```

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(Ag:Pb), funs(. * value)) %>%    # replace 1s with `value`
    group_by(lat_orig, long_orig, unit) %>%    # group by non-value columns
    summarise_at(vars(-value), sum)    # take sums of element columns

## Source: local data frame [1 x 10]
## Groups: lat_orig, long_orig [?]
## 
##   lat_orig long_orig   unit    Ag    As    Au    Cu    Fe    Mn    Pb
##      <dbl>     <dbl> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1  40.5525 -106.7736    ppm  -0.5     0 -0.02    15  1000     0    30
```